# Get Hex Value of UChar in ICU4C

Tags: c++, unicode, icu

I'm working with ICU in a C++ library.
How can I get the Unicode Hex value of a UChar? For example, 'a' should be equal to 0x0041 (http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something simple like

```
std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0')
          << static_cast<int>('a') << '\n';
```

Though it prints `0061` and not `0041`, which is the correct hex value for `a`.

Comment: @SZH Is it too much hassle to look at the documentation?

Comment: Here's the final code: `std::hex << std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0')
         << static_cast<int>(UnicodeString("A").charAt(0)) << '\n';` (This uses Unicode instead of UTF-8)